# Ruby change type in array of hashes from float to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such array data:

```
[#<PriceList id: 463134, distributor_id: 6, brand: "Mann-filter", article_nr: "W712/22", price: 5405.0, quantity: "50", waittime: 1, description: "Фильтр масл OPEL 1.2-3.0L (OC90)", created_at: "2013-01-30 16:35:34", updated_at: "2013-01-30 16:35:34", art_group: "Фильтр масл OPEL 1.2-3.0L (OC90)", oem_number: nil>, #<PriceList id: 517164, distributor_id: 6, brand: "Mann-filter", article_nr: "W712/22", price: 5442.0, quantity: "500", waittime: 3, description: "Фильтр масляный OPEL/GM/DAEWOO", created_at: "2013-01-30 16:42:26", updated_at: "2013-01-30 16:42:26", art_group: "Фильтр масляный OPEL/GM/DAEWOO", oem_number: nil>, #<PriceList id: 463135, distributor_id: 6, brand: "Mann-filter", article_nr: "W712/22(10)", price: 5101.0, quantity: "20", waittime: 1, description: "Фильтр масл.без упак.OPEL/GM (OC90Of)", created_at: "2013-01-30 16:35:34", updated_at: "2013-01-30 16:35:34", art_group: "Фильтр масл.без упак.OPEL/GM (OC90Of)", oem_number: nil>, ... etc
```

how can i change price type?

i try

```
@non_original2 = @non_original2.map { |e| e[:price].to_i }
```

but as result i see only price values... How can i change my array, so that price field in all hashes become integer value?

Comment: Why not define it as such in your model?

Comment: @MarkThomas it must be float, just in one controller must be int (ceil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about

```
@non_original2.each { |e| e[:price] = e[:price].to_i }
```

This changes every `PriceList` item in the list (and does not copy the list).

Using your approach results in a list of price values, because `map` collects the *result* of the block. The result of `e[:price].to_i` is an integer (the prices you see).

Comment: can't convert Symbol into Integer

Comment: Are you sure? If your `@non_original2 = @non_original2.map { |e| e[:price].to_i }` works, `e[:price].to_i` in my code should work too.

Comment: oh, sorry my mistake, my code is (symbol @ is changed bu 5!):   5!non_original = non_original.flatten!    

    5!non_original2 = 5!non_original.map { |e| e[:price].to_i }   than you code work, but nothing happend(

Comment: nothing happened? is `@non_original2.first[:price]` and Integer or a Float?

Comment: Even after the `each`-line from my answer? Probably your `PriceList` class converts input to float (in method `[]=`) when assigning `:price`.

Comment: Ah, probably `PriceList` is a `ActiveRecord::Base` class with `price` defined as `:float`. If you want to have integer prices for all `PriceList` instances, migrate the fields data type. If its just for displaying it, convert in just before displaying it (`"foo: %d" % 3.14 #=> "foo: 3"`)

Comment: you mean convert in view?

Comment: Yes, you could do a `list_item[:price].to_i` in your view